# Acrobat 8 on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, adobe-acrobat

Here's the situation I'm in. I have Acrobat 8 on Wows 7 (64-bit) and anytime I create PDFs any numbers on the page I'm PDFing come through as garbage. Everything else on the page comes out fine, just the numbers are messed up. They appear as random symbols. I've uninstalled, reinstalled. Applied all updates, not applied updates, nothing seems to help. Mayube I'm a bad searcher, can't put in the right search terms, but I can't find anything that seems to point me in a direction on this. ANy ideas?

Comment: Virtual machine to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

Adobe does not list Acrobat 8 as compatible with Windows 7 in any version.  Not sure if that could be an issue.  There are a number of posts suggesting Adobe 9 as being the version for Windows 7.

Are you trying Version 8.1?  That is supposed to have  improved Vista compatability and addressed a printing issue [Adobe 8.1 update](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=3661)  have also seen a comment that after downloading the update go into the the PDF printer properties, go to "advanced" and tick the "print directly to printer" box

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 7 Compatibility page also does not list Acrobat 8 (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Search.aspx?l=en-us&type=Software&s=acrobat%208). You may have to upgrade to get it to work with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Acrobat 8 works in Windows 7.  I think you need at least Acrobat 9.

However, if you are only looking to print and create a PDF, you may want to try:

[doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/),

[PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/),

[BullZip PDF](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php)

All of them are free PDF printer drivers that allows you to print to a PDF file.